# nvEncodeAPI.dll refrence could not be added to my C# project

Tags: c#

i have a C# project about cloudgaming testbed. i wanna add nvEncodeAPI.dll to my project, but this error has been occured :

> A refrence '*.dll' could not be added. please make sure that the file
>   is accessible, and that is a valid assembly or COM component.

i searched in stack and there were some solutions but they didnt work for me.
Does anyone know why a dll might not import or how to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Right click on your project and choose Add Reference.

2) Choose the Browse tab and go find your assembly

3) After adding the assembly include that reference in your class or form where ever you are going to use

using myownclass;

Comment: Do you really think OP did something different than your answer?

Comment: Look like your dll is not a valid assembly or COM component.

Comment: Did you try to register it with regsvr32.exe ?

Comment: hi
i added my all file, but I recieved an error that I mentioned before.
i tried to register it with regsvr32.exe too, but it didn't work. @Yanga